# Firebase not found on Android API 21

Tags: android, gradle, firebase

I'm having issues with Firebase, in that my app crashes immediately upon launching and displays this error:

```
com.delbridge.seth.alarm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.delbridge.seth.alarm, PID: 10646
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.delbridge.seth.alarm-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4967)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4559)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4499)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.delbridge.seth.alarm-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4952)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4559) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4499) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
                                                                          at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                ... 13 more
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

The app runs fine on my phone running Android 6.0.1. However it crashes on my tablet that runs Android 5.0.2 (My min SDK version)

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.delbridge.seth.alarm"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    //multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
compile 'org.jdeferred:jdeferred-android-aar:1.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: at first `minSdkVersion 17` and `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"`

Comment: You're only using Firebase Ads. Isn't there another Firebase dependency that you need?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @cricket_007 Google's guide for in app ads only mentioned that one dependency (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Comment: It's an excerpt. Meaning you include that to reference the Admob libraries, but if you want to use the core Firebase libraries, follow the link above here

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not interested in using the core libraries. I don't even make explicit firebase calls. I only need it for AdViews/AdRequests. It works fine on API 23, but not on 21.